# Derivative of vectors dimension do not agree

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces

I have two n by 1 vectors $\mathbf w,\mathbf v$ with respect to $\mathbf w$, and $\mathbf v$ is some function to $\mathbf w$. so I can get a scalar from $\mathbf w^T\mathbf v$, I want to take derivative of that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf w}(\mathbf w^T\mathbf v) = (\mathbf w^T)'\mathbf v+\mathbf w^T\mathbf v'$, it is known that $\frac{\partial\mathbf x^TA}{\partial\mathbf x} = A^T$ (easily googled), So I think $(\mathbf w^T)'=I_{n\times n}$, and the previous derivative term will become:

($\mathbf w^T\mathbf v)' = (\mathbf w^T)'\mathbf v+\mathbf w^T\mathbf v'=I\mathbf v+\mathbf w^T\mathbf v'$

The problem is for the first term, $I\mathbf v$ is with dimension n by 1, while the second term $\mathbf w^T\mathbf v'$ is with dimension 1 by n by something, the two terms' dimension do not agree with each other. Which step is wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $f(A)=A^T$ then $f$ clearly isn't the identity map.